# How can i implement WCF security using self signed certificate?

Tags: c#, wcf

I did google it for setting up my WCF service using certificate security and i found a bunch of articles but i am not able to decide which article is easy to follow. Further when i type those commands some tools are there in Visual Studio Command Prompt whereas some aren't. Can anybody tell me the precise steps or point to me some nice links?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most difficult part about this is the configuration.  Otherwise, the task is simply to create a client and server certificate and install the certificates.  I assume you know how to do that.  Certificates must be placed in Trusted People store.  A mostly stripped-down config is pasted below.  I've used this successfully (you'll have to replace values like "address here"...so go through this config line-by-line and decide what you'd like to name things.  I put this togehter with the help of two tutorials, but I don't have the links anymore.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint name="MyServiceEndpoint" address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceBinding" contract="IMyContract"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="address here"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<client>
  <endpoint name="MyClientEndpoint" address="address here" behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyClientBinding" contract="IMyContract">
    <identity>
      <dns value="ServerCertificate"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata/>
      <!--need this for mex to work properly!-->

      <!-- 
        The serviceCredentials behavior allows you to define a service certificate.
        A service certificate is used by the service to authenticate itself to its clients and to provide message protection.
        This configuration references the "localhost" certificate installed during the set up instructions.
      -->
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="ServerCertificate" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
        <clientCertificate>
          <!-- 
          Setting the certificateValidationMode to PeerOrChainTrust means that if the certificate 
          is in the user's Trusted People store, then it is trusted without performing a
          validation of the certificate's issuer chain. This setting is used here for convenience so that the 
          sample can be run without having certificates issued by a certificate authority (CA).
          This setting is less secure than the default, ChainTrust. The security implications of this 
          setting should be carefully considered before using PeerOrChainTrust in production code. 
          -->
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="CurrentUser"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <!-- 
      The clientCredentials behavior allows you to define a certificate to present to a service.
      A certificate is used by a client to authenticate itself to the service and provide message integrity.
      This configuration references the "client.com" certificate installed during the setup instructions.
      -->
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="WFCClient" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <!-- 
          Setting the certificateValidationMode to PeerOrChainTrust means that if the certificate 
          is in the user's Trusted People store, then it is trusted without performing a
          validation of the certificate's issuer chain. This setting is used here for convenience so that the 
          sample can be run without having certificates issued by a certificate authority (CA).
          This setting is less secure than the default, ChainTrust. The security implications of this 
          setting should be carefully considered before using PeerOrChainTrust in production code. 
          -->
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="CurrentUser"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="MyClientBinding" maxConnections="25000" listenBacklog="25000" portSharingEnabled="false" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="24:11:30" transferMode="Buffered" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2097152000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152000" maxBufferPoolSize="2097152000">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2000000000" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxDepth="2000000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000000"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="MyServiceBinding" maxConnections="25000" listenBacklog="25000" portSharingEnabled="false" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="24:12:35" transferMode="Buffered" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="10485760" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" maxBufferPoolSize="104857600">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2000000000" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxDepth="2000000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000000"/>
      <security>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```